# How should I filter a IReactiveList bound to a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

my ViewModel has a IReactiveList which is bound to a grid in the View. I now want to filter the data based on user-driven events. My question is what is the best approach for this?

The only way I can see is to create a new ReactiveList instance containing just the filtered data and set it to the ViewModel IReactiveList property each time the filter event changes. I don't like this as I'd be creating new ReactiveList instance on each filter event.

Is there a better way? Obviously I could directly manipulate the View Grid filters in the VM but this would break the MVVM-ness.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `IReactiveList` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, can't you just expose a `CollectionView` from your VM instead and change the filtering on that?

```
public class MyVM
{
    private readonly IReactiveList data;

    //bind grid to this
    public ListCollectionView DataCollectionView { get; private set; }

    public MyVM(IReactiveList data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.DataCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(this.data);
        this.DataCollectionView.Filter = FilterData;
    }

    private bool FilterData(object o)
    {    
        //filter your data how ever you want in here. 
    }
}
```

At the point your filter changes, just call `this.DataCollectionView.Refresh()` and the data will be refiltered.

Comment: thanks for the response but how would i do this? I can't see any CollectionView property.

Comment: I needed to use - but thanks a lot: (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.data))